# Strange backspace behavior

Tags: vim, gvim

In both command line `vim` and `gvim` alike, I have a situation where the backspace functionality behaves like some of my old `vi` experiences.

If I press backspace in edit mode, the character is not erased until I return to command mode. If I start with `vim -u NONE -N` or `vim -u NORC -N`, then backspace behaves as I would expect.

I tried isolating the problem in my `vimrc` by placing `finish` above the lines until the problem was fixed; however, even after placing `finish` on the top line, the behavior persists.

My `vimrc` is here: http://pastie.org/9602002

The last line was just added today by suggestion of the wiki, but it offered no behavior change. It seems like the problem exists outside my `vimrc`, but I have no idea where.

EDIT: I have isolated the issue. It appears `vim -N` is all that is required to mitigate this issue. Is there a way to set no-compatible mode from `vimrc`?

Comment: What is the output of `verbose set backspace?`. The backspace setting should fix this.

Comment: `backspace=indent,eol,start`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `set nocompatible` in `vimrc` appears to have resolved the issue.

For some reason, this wasn't being set when the `vimrc` was loaded.

EDIT: `nocompatible` is only set when loading a user rc file (`~/.vimrc`) and not a global one. If you use the global `vimrc`, you must set `nocompatible` yourself; otherwise, it will be set for you.

Comment: For "some" reason? You *don't have a vimrc*. Your vimrc should be there: `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: That isn't correct. I use the global one in `/etc/vimrc` or `/etc/vim/vimrc` depending on the distro. I had talked this over with `#vim` on Freenode, and they found it perplexing as well.

Comment: `nocompatible` is only set automatically when a user vimrc is found. Since you don't have one there is no reason to expect it to happen. *Your* settings are supposed to go in `~/.vimrc` (and `~/.vim/vimrc` if you use 7.4) and nowhere else.